# ¿Cómo ordenar algunos datos del archivo /etc/passwd?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Quiero ordenar los datos que da al poner:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

Por ejemplo:

```
lperez:FXWUuZ.vwXttg:500:501:usuario Luis Perez:/home/lperez:/bin/bash
```

Debería mostrarme:

```
Usuario=lperez, Descripcion=usuario Luis Perez, Directorio Home=/home/lperez, Shell=BASH
```

Lo que hice fue separar los datos con:

```
#!/bin/bash
a= cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

y así de cada campo que necesito. Pero no se como hacer para que me aparezca como en el ejemplo

Comment: Yo usaría `awk` para procesar cada línea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sé exactamente para que lo necesitas o si necesitas que sea algo hecho de una forma muy profesional, pero si no es el caso, podrías usar un simple awk con un field separator de ':' y añadir texto dentro del print:

```
$ awk -F':' '{print "Usuario=" $1 ", Descripcion=Usuario "$1, ", Directorio Home=" $6 ", Shell="$7}' /etc/passwd
```

Donde:

1. -F es el field separator, vas a separar las columnas con dos puntos ":".
2. $1 es la primera columna que es la del usuario.
3. $6 es la sexta columna del directorio home.
4. $7 es la septima columna que indica la shell.

Parte del resultado es, en mí caso, el siguiente:

```
...
Usuario=test, Descripcion=Usuario Test , Directorio Home=/home/test, Shell=/bin/sh
Usuario=www-data, Descripcion=Usuario www-data , Directorio Home=/var/www, Shell=/usr/sbin/nologin
Usuario=nobody, Descripcion=Usuario nobody , Directorio Home=/nonexistent, Shell=/usr/sbin/nologin
...
```

La descripción suele ir en la $5 columna, pero algunos no la tienen definida.